# Execute PS at start up

Tags: powershell

I'm running a .bat file to call a PS file at start up,

```
Powershell -command "C:\temp\VPNVPNcli_test.ps1"
```

I get this error

```
C:\temp\VPNVPNcli_test.ps1 : The term 'C:\temp\VPNVPNcli_test.ps1' is not
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\temp\VPNVPNcli_test.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-Command` is for executing commands, if you would like to pass a script file you need to use `-File`

```
Powershell.exe -File "C:\temp\VPNVPNcli_test.ps1"
```

It would probably also be a good idea to do an executionpolicy bypass if you do not have consistent execution policy across your domain.